# Disable submit with key press event

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a form with some textbox
When a user press the enter key in a textbox starts the submit of the form

i want that there is the submit only when the user press the submit button.

how can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Javascript code

```
    function disableEnterKey(e)
    {
         var key;


         if(window.event)
              key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
         else
              key = e.which;     //firefox

         if(key == 13)
              return false;
         else
              return true;
    }
```

**KeyCode 13 stands for the enter key.**

And keep textbox as this:

```
<input type=”text” name=”mytext” onKeyPress=”return disableEnterKey(event)”>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add javascript handler on Keydown and Keypress events (I'm using jQuery):

```
$(input).bind("keydown", null, onKeydown);

onKeydown: function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13)
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="txtInput" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)">
<script language="JavaScript">
    function disableEnterKey(e)
    {
        var key;
        if(window.event){
            key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
        }else{
            key = e.which; //firefox     
        }
        return (key != 13);<br/>
    }
</script>
```